# $(-1)/(2i/\{-2\lambda\})=-i\lambda$ - this can't be true?

Tags: complex-analysis, solution-verification, inverse-problems

Maybe I am confused but in the screenshot below, there is a line saying that
$$
c_1=(-1)/(2i/\{-2\lambda\})=-i\lambda,\qquad \hat{c_1}=(-1)/(2i/2\lambda)=i\lambda.
$$

Isn't that false? Shouldn't it be
$$
c_1=(-1)/(2i/\{-2\lambda\})=\lambda/i,\qquad \hat{c_1}=(-1)/(2i/2\lambda)=-\lambda/i?
$$

By the way: The formula behind that is
$$
c_1=b(\zeta)/(da/d\zeta)
$$
evaluated at $\zeta=\frac{i\lambda}{2}$.

[image]

Comment: $\frac1i=\frac i{i\cdot i}=\frac i{-1}=-i$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since $\frac1i=-i$, there is no contradiction.

Comment: I see. Very stupid of me. Thanks!